# Shell script -- how to store curl command WITH variables result into another variable?

Tags: shell, curl

Currently I have a curl command that I want to store in a local variable. I know I could use `` or $() to get it done, but a variable inside the command stops me from doing so.

`local sample_mapping="$(curl -XGET '${search_host}/${index}/_mapping')"`

where search_host and index are two variables previously set. This command fails because `Couldn't resolve host '$search_host'`

The other posts didn't talk about what to do when dealing with variables. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the command in your command substitution:

```
curl -XGET '${search_host}/${index}/_mapping'
```

This command will not work on its own.  The problem that you are observing is due to the single quotes, not to the use of command substitution, `$(...)`.

Inside single-quotes, variables are not expanded.  Since you need variable expansion, use double-quotes:

```
curl -XGET "${search_host}/${index}/_mapping"
```

Putting the above in your original command:

```
local sample_mapping="$(curl -XGET "${search_host}/${index}/_mapping")"
```

Note that *quotes and command substitutions can nest* : the fact that there are double quotes *inside* the command substitution has no effect on the double quotes *outside* of the command substitution.

#### Example

Let's define some variables:

```
$ search_host=http://google.com
$ index=index.html
```

Now, let's try the command with single-quotes:

```
$ a=$(curl -XGET '$search_host/$index')
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: $search_host
```

The above failed with an error message similar to the one you observed: `Could not resolve host: $search_host`

Let's try again with double-quotes:

```
$ a=$(curl -XGET "$search_host/$index")
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   229  100   

229    0     0    520      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   521
```

The above succeeded.

Comment: I removed the single quote and used double quote instead, the problem remains. the error msg is still the same.

Comment: @JChao That would appear to mean that there is a problem with the host that you are accessing.  Try my example (using google) and verify that it works before trying your host.

Comment: Alright you're correct. I had another syntax error....... Thanks for your help! So just to make sure, in the future, I'll just have to replace single quote with double quote? That should solve the problem, right?

Comment: @JChao When you want variable expansion, as you do here, use double-quotes.  If you want to suppress _all_ shell expansions, use single-quotes.